# Background image blurry on small screens (looks fine in Wordpress/Chrome editors, but on actual phone it's blurry

Tags: css, wordpress, image, responsive-images, wpbakery

I've been struggling with this one for a while, so hoping someone might be able to help me out.

I'm using WP Bakery plugin, and the page background images I set are really blurry on smaller screens. All looks fine on the Wordpress/Chrome visual editors, but on an actual phone/tablet the photo doesn't resize, so it's just a blurry mess. The CSS is as follows:

`body {
    background-color: #00657f!important;
    background-image: url(http://414kiting.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/player_hantu_light-50.jpeg) !important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`

website address is 414kiting.com

Any help hugely appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code **in the question** to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE] and [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Can you please share the URL of your website where I can take a look?

Comment: Hey PreP the URL is  414kiting.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution- this will surely work :), Can you please try this with media query :

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px ) {

    body {
        background-attachment: initial;
    }
body:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://414kiting.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/player_hantu_light-50.jpeg) !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

}
```

Comment: Amarjit - you are my hero! I've been staring at this for months, and you've solved it just like that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome Fi Dunnington :) 
you can like my answer above !

Answer (score 0):

Lots of mobile browsers don't support

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Best way to solve this is to make a media query for tablet sizes and lower to make the background-attachment: scroll or initial and then try to simulate the effect or just discard it on mobile devices.

Edit: typo

Comment: Thanks Elian. I tried that, but it hasn't changed anything. Thanks anyway!

Comment: With all do respect, yes it was. It was exactly what was wrong with your problem. ;)

Comment: @Elian Android Browser is the only one that doesn't support `background-attachment`. iOS Safari only has an issue with `fixed` in conjunction with `cover` for size. To say `lots of mobile browsers` is incorrect. https://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment

Comment: @disinfor Samsung Browser, Baidu & Blackberry browsers, Android browser & Opera mini also have no support for fixed. Safari has problems with fixed being used with cover. Chrome is listed as supported, but it's not. So yeah, lots of browsers don't support background-attachment: fixed. In fact, the majority of mobile browsers have no support for it.

Comment: @Elian The browsers you listed are at almost 0% global usage. I just think the opening line of your answer is incorrect - the rest of your answer is perfectly fine and a completely viable solution.

Comment: @disinfor Well, the browsers that lack support are, among others, Mobile chrome, Samsung default browser and iOS safari ( when used with background cover). So, in terms of global usage, it's pretty high up there. Bottom line is, the vast majority of browsers being used most don't support this. So it's best to look for an alternative. That's all I was saying in my answer.

Comment: @Elian right on. I still agree with your assessment on media queries as a solid answer.

Comment: @disinfor fair enough. :)